# AppleScript/ Mac: Color detect and execute mouse click

Tags: applescript, color-detection, onmouseclick

I have a very annoying, repeating task on macOS. 
Basically I have a list within a Google Chrome website. I want to detect a specific color and every time this color appears, I want to select that field (mouse click) and then execute a keystroke. Searching for hours now and trying to wrap my head around it but am not experienced enough with Mac/Applescript/Automator.

Any ideas or good links to hint me to?

Comment: Are you on iPad/iPhone (iOS) or on Mac (macOS)? What's a *"Google Chrome website*" please?

Comment: apologies. Google Chrome Website on macOS Catalina on an iMac

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't believe you can detect colours on the screen with Automator. I think you will need something like Python's `pyautogui` which can continually grab the screen and look for colours or shapes. This should get you started... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60448513/2836621

Comment: Well, if you can do it with a Python program, you can therefore do it with Automator. However, you don't need a third-party download. If you did want to "detect" colours, you could do it with a similar technique by acquiring the colour of the pixel by taking a 1x1 screenshot at the appropriate coordinates. But, if this is on a website, you can just use JavaScript to get the properties of the coloured object (and thus its colour); JavaScript can also issue a click to page elements.

Comment: @CJK Would you be able to point me to a very simple example of how/where you would put some Javascript on a Mac to make it find some element on a webpage and click on it please?

Comment: Sure. In fact, I know StackOverflow has tons of these examples, as I’ve written a few myself.  If you try searching for the AppleScript tag (which I think one does by enclosing it in square brackets) together with a search term `click on element in webpage`, that will hopefully bring up a bunch. For more specific help, you’d need to provide specific information, including the webpage that you’re querying.